# Inserting HashMap Values to a table using ibatis

Tags: java, sql, hashmap, ibatis

I found this on http://old.nabble.com/insert-statement-td21157498.html
I want to do the same thing .I have two columns in my table .I am able to insert hash map values by mapping the hashmap key to the column name.Now i want put the key values pairs in the table irrespective of key name.

Pasted from the  link above.

I would like to write a dynamic insert statement, but both fields and values are dynamic.

I mean

```
<insert id="someIDhere" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap">

    insert into table_one (

        !!! dynamic list of keys from the HashMap

    ) values (

        !!! values

    );

  </insert>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. The link you have posted has a solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hashmap could be:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hm.put("col1", 1);
    hm.put("col2", 23);
    hm.put("col3", 34);
```

then call the insert someIDhere with the hm as parameter.

```
insert into table_one (

    COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3

) values (

    #col1#, #col2#, #col3#

);
```