# IBATIS - Insert dynamic HashMap from Spring to Oracle

Tags: ibatis

Some background on the issue. From the front end, I have two select boxes with the multiple property. One box is for approved items, the other is for ignored items. I place these into a Map with the key being the company's UID, and the value either being "Y" or "N" depending on which box the UID is in. [Inserting HashMap Values to a table using ibatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847761/inserting-hashmap-values-to-a-table-using-ibatis) provided some assistance, but the answer involved manually putting the  entries, where as I am dynamically creating the map, so not sure what the keys will be. Below is the code for the Java:

```
// Set up the map object for the back end
        Map<Integer, String> posMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        // Get the approved mailers
        String[] mailerList = request.getParameterValues("approved");                   
        if (mailerList != null && mailerList.length > 0)
        {
            for(String mailer : mailerList)
            {
                posMap.put(Integer.parseInt(mailer), "Y");
            }
        }
        // reset the mailerList
        mailerList = null;
        // get the ignored mailers
        mailerList = request.getParameterValues("ignored");
        if (mailerList != null && mailerList.length > 0)
        {
            for(String mailer : mailerList)
            {
                posSampleMap.put(Integer.parseInt(mailer), "N");
            }
        }
        // only update POS if the map is not empty
        if(!posMap.isEmpty())
        {               
            updateMapper.updatePOSSampling(posMap);
        }
```

Normally, I would have something like this in the mapper.xml file:

```
<update id="updatePOSSampling" parameterType="hashmap">
   UPDATE <table_name>
   SET sampling_enabled = ${myMapValue}
   WHERE mailer_name = ${myMapKey}
</update>
```

In the link I provided, they were manually putting in the keys and values, and as such, the example IBATIS could refer to the key. Since I'm not sure what my key is, what would be the best way to generate this query? I've got a temporary workaround of sending a two dimension array, but I feel using a Map DO would be a better way. Thanks in advance for any assistance.