# Select query from one data source and Insert into different data source - mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

OK so I am working with mybatis.
There is a select statement which brings & inserts multiple (150 + column records) results from one database(DB1) and the results are being used for an insert statement into an another database(DB2)..

Really didn't think of creating a POJO class with multiple variables to store the data and retrieve - I believe there must be a better way of doing this in mybatis.. does mybatis have ResultSet or something similar to work with; without needing to create any Java class?

> UPDATE

Able to get the data using List and trying to add this hashmap to the insert query dynamically.. posted a different question here [Using HashMap dynamically for parameter mapping in mybatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213950/using-hashmap-dynamically-for-parameter-mapping-in-mybatis/68216214#68216214) so marked this one as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the resultType attribute to map the table data will be placed into a HashMap where the keys will be column names and the values will be the column contents.

Something like this:

```
<select id="selectOne"  parameterType="cn.lyn4ever.entity.User"  resultType="java.util.HashMap">
       select id,username,telphone from user
 </select>
```

Take a look at this example:
https://programmer.group/return-to-map-in-mybatis.html

Comment: Well actually this is what I want to avoid (creating a POJO class).. cant imagine working with 150+ columns eh...

Comment: That worked for select query but for the insert query I am still looking for answers.. I am exactly looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847761/inserting-hashmap-values-to-a-table-using-ibatis